# The number of ways the word can appear

Tags: combinatorics

How to find how many way can the word : $ABRACADABRA$ appear in the pyramid from up to down in the same order of the word

[image]

Comment: A simpler problem: Ignore all but the top three lines.  How many ways you can you form the sequence "ABR"?

Answer (score 1):

At each step you only have two choice of left or right so it is $2^{10}$